# SQL Server : joining 2 tables where each row has unique PKEY value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2017

I am attempting to join 2 tables with an equivalent amount of columns and where each column is named the same. `Tb1` is an MS Access table that I have imported to SQL Server. `Tb2` is a table that is updated from tb1 quarterly and is used to generate reports.

I have gone into design view and ensured that all column datatypes are the same and have the same names. Likewise, every row in each table is assigned a unique integer value in a column named `PKEY`.

What I would like to do is add all new entries present in `tb1` (the MS Access table) to the existing `tb2`. I believe this can be done by writing a query that loads all unique pkeys found in `tb1` (AKA load all keys that are **NOT** found in both tables, only load unique keys belonging to rows in the access table) and then appending these entries into `Tb2`.

Not really sure where to start when writing this query, I tried something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tb1 
WHERE PKEY <> Tb2.PKEY
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The title says SQL-Server, but the tag says MySQL. Which are you really using?

Comment: microsoft sql server 2017

Comment: I've reopened the question since the duplicate is for MySQL. But I think the same techniques should work with SQL-Server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend `not exists`:

```
select tb1.*
from tb1
where not exists (select 1 from tb2 where tb2.pkey = tb1.pkey);
```

You can put an `insert` before this to insert the rows into the second table.

Comment: You could also try NOT IN, it will do the same thing, but the syntax would be a little different

Comment: @Kelevra . . . I discourage the use of `NOT IN` with subqueries, because it does not handle `NULL` values intuitively.

Answer (score 0):

`Insert into tb2 Select * from tb1 Where tb1.id not in (select Id from tb2)`

The script above inserts records to tb2 from the results the first select query.

The select query only returns records with an ID that is not listed in the select sub query.

Comment: Although code answers are acceptable can you add some explanation. Your answer will be read by people in the future so you need to add a description so that they can understand your solution.